# Upload file into XAMPP Server using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to upload file  into XAMPP server but I could not see any file into server project folder.But I see byte writing completed.What is the problem in my code.Please help me anybody.

Sample code::

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServletCom {

    public static void main(String[] args)
      throws Exception
   {

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      BufferedReader br = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;
      DataInputStream inStream = null;

      InputStream is = null;
      OutputStream os = null;
      boolean ret = false;
      String StrMessage = "";
      String exsistingFileName = "C:\\Users\\hossain\\Desktop\\photo\\image\\text.txt";
      String fileName="text.txt";

      String lineEnd = "";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary =  "*****";


  int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

  byte[] buffer;

  int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;


  String responseFromServer = "";

  String urlString = "http://local.ebajar/";


  try
  {
   //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( new File(exsistingFileName) );

   // open a URL connection to the Servlet 

   URL url = new URL(urlString);


   // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

   // Allow Inputs
   conn.setDoInput(true);

   // Allow Outputs
   conn.setDoOutput(true);

   // Don't use a cached copy.
   conn.setUseCaches(false);

   // Use a post method.
   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

   dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );

   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
   //dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload";"+ " filename="" + exsistingFileName +""" + lineEnd);
   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);



   // create a buffer of maximum size

   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

   // read file and write it into form...

   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

   while (bytesRead > 0)
   {
    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
   }

   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

   System.out.println("write complete........" );
   // close streams

   fileInputStream.close();
   dos.flush();
   dos.close();


  }
  catch (MalformedURLException ex)
  {
   System.out.println("From ServletCom CLIENT REQUEST:"+ex);
  }

  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
   System.out.println("From ServletCom CLIENT REQUEST:"+ioe);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("From ServletCom CLIENT REQUEST:"+e);
  }

   }
}
```

Comment: You need a script which accepts your data on server-side, e.g. something like `upload.php`.

Comment: Can I see the uploaded file in server folder location?

Comment: The code you wrote uses `POST` and seems to upload something with Content-Type "multipart/form-data". So I expect you wanted to upload a file. Do you want to download a web page? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to write a file to server(tomacat/xampp server) using java client application. I want to see my uploaded file into project folder path physically. sorry for may bad English.

Comment: I can upload my file into tomcat server project folder but I want to upload my file any local image server may other tomact/xampp project folder location

Comment: OK, as I already said, you need some server-side logic to accept your file and save it to web-server's file system. Web-servers (like Apache) or Servlet-Engines (like Tomcat) do NOT save posted files automatically. You need a script or a servlet or a CGI-program to do this. Your java client may contain some errors, but without the server-side logic it will never run.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I solved my problem using ftp server with java client program.I think it is better and easy to use ftp program than httpRrlConnection client program.